# Pymongo delete_many TypeError

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, typeerror

I used this all the time to delete entries that are older than 24h:

```
entries.delete_many({"Time": {"$lt": time.time()-24*60*60} })
```

And it has worked for a long time but now it suddenly throws an error:

```
Type: TypeError (Inappropriate argument type.)
```

Was it deprecated or something? How does it work again?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why that would have stopped working but you should try passing a datetime object instead of an int.

`datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(24,60,60)`